# Thinking Sphinx search through constant value

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-3.2, thinking-sphinx

I am using rails 3.2 and thinking_sphinx gem and have following code in my model:

```
#encoding: utf-8
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :feedback_type

  FEEDBACK_TYPE = { 1 => "found cheaper", 2 => "complaints", 3 => "wishes",
                   4 => "other" }

  define_index do
    indexes feedback_type
    has created_at, updated_at
    set_property delta: true
  end
end
```

and in my feedback_controller I have:

```
  @feedbacks = Feedback.search(params[:search], page: params[:page], 
                       per_page: 10,
                       sort_mode: :extended)
```

feedback_type is an integer type field in database and it has values from 1 to 4 according to FEEDBACK_TYPE values. In view I am showing feedback type with Feedback::FEEDBACK_TYPE[feedback.feedback_type]. Can I implement search in my model by FEEDBACK_TYPE string values typing for example "wishes" in search form? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not actually try this but following should work:

```
    define_index do
        indexes "case feedback_table_name.feedback_type 
                 when 1 then 'found cheaper'
                 when 2 then 'complaints'
                 when 3 then 'wishes'
                 when 4 then 'other'
                 end",  :as=>:feedback_type
        has created_at, updated_at
        set_property delta: true
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can write it more powerfull, like this:

```
FEEDBACK_TYPE = { 1 => "found cheaper", 2 => "complaints", 3 => "wishes",
               4 => "other" }

kind_of_types = lambda do 
  str = 'case feedback_table_name. feedback_type '
  FEEDBACK_TYPE.each { |type| str += "when #{type[0]} then '#{type[1]}' " }
  str += 'end'    
end

define_index do
  indexes kind_of_types, as: :feedback_type
  has created_at, updated_at
  set_property delta: true
end
```